# SQL Server Query-Update Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could you please anyone help me out with SQL Server query. I want to insert Table 1 records to Table 2 as per business rule.

**Business Rule1-** If the **Ref_No.** is same and **MsgCreatedDt** are different then insert those records and update very first record (**Remarks** column) as blank and rest as duplicate.

**Business Rule2-** If the Ref_No. is same and MsgCreatedDt are also same then insert only one record.

Below are the input and output.

Input: Table1

```
ID  Ref_No  MsgCreatedDt    Remarks
1   Ref1    22-03-2020 17:39    
2   Ref1    22-03-2020 17:42    
3   Ref1    22-03-2020 18:10    
4   Ref2    22-03-2020 16:11    
5   Ref2    22-03-2020 16:11
```

Output: Table2

```
ID  Ref_No  MsgCreatedDt        Remarks
1   Ref1    22-03-2020 17:39    
2   Ref1    22-03-2020 17:42    Duplicate
3   Ref1    22-03-2020 18:10    Duplicate
4   Ref2    22-03-2020 16:11
```

[image]

Comment: Please **DO NOT** post sample data/code as images. Instead post it as _formatted text_

Comment: Look into `merge`. This might still be a two step process though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
insert into Table2 (ref_no, msgcreateddt, remarks)
select t.ref_no, t.msgcreateddt,
  case when t.rn1 > 1 then 'Duplicate' end
from (  
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by ref_no order by msgcreateddt) rn1,
    row_number() over (partition by ref_no, msgcreateddt order by (select null)) rn2
  from Table1
) t  
where t.rn2 = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cc3bd53eb01c32c752f0381f179ca65).
Results:

```
>   ID | Ref_No | MsgCreatedDt            | Remarks  
> ---: | :----- | :---------------------- | :--------
> 1    | Ref1   | 2020-03-22 17:39:00.000 | null     
> 2    | Ref1   | 2020-03-22 17:42:00.000 | Duplicate
> 3    | Ref1   | 2020-03-22 18:10:00.000 | Duplicate
> 4    | Ref2   | 2020-03-22 16:11:00.000 | null
```

Comment: Thank's a lot forpas

Comment: There is no specific reason to accept latest one. I just accepted. Actually i thought both answer will be accepted but one got reversed.

Comment: Any number of answers can be upvoted, but only one could be accepted. The accepted answer should be the one you personally ended up using. Upvotes should be given to useful answers. When I accept an answer I also upvote it

Answer (score 2):

Slightly simpler than a double rownumber method:

```
  insert into Table2
  select
    min(id),
    ref_no,
    msgcreateddt,
    case when msgcreateddt > min(msgcreateddt) over (partition by ref_no) then 'Duplicate' end 
  from Table1
  group by ref_no, msgcreateddt
```

It works because window functions are done after group by; the group by removes rows that have exactly duplicated dates, then the window function (`min(msgcreateddt) over(partition by ref_no)` - it works out the min date per ref_no) is used to work out if the current row's `msgcreateddt` is greater than that min date

Comment: @ImranAzam . . . This is definitely the better approach -- pretty much exactly specifying the logic  you are asking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff will you clarify *better approach*?